# Remove white space before a single chapter

Tags: spacing, chapters, book-design

I've searched this sites for similar questions, but can only find answers that remove the space for every chapter, whereas I only want it removed in one chapter. The MWE is quite minimal `:)`

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
Hello
\chapter{Chapter 2}
Bonjour
\end{document}
```

How can I remove the white space above only one of the chapters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
Hello

\makeatletter
\let\savedchap\@makechapterhead
\def\@makechapterhead{\vspace*{-1cm}\savedchap}
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\let\@makechapterhead\savedchap
\makeatletter

Bonjour

\chapter{Chapter 3}

Ol\'a

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I adapt this to a document in which I have a master file and I then insert chapters using the ´\include´ command? I Have been trying most variations to no avail.

Comment: @user2770617 the use of `\include` would not affect this at all, just put the redefinition either before the include or at the top of the included file, of course not all document classes necessarily define chapters in terms of `\@makechapterhead`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if you have a  `\chapter*{Chapter 2}` instead of `\chapter{Chapter 2}`. Any alternative?

Comment: Just solved my problem. Use `\@makeschapterhead` instead of `\@makechapterhead` when you have the starred version of `\chapter`

Answer (score 2):

David's answer is correct, but a bit too overcomplicated. A cleaner solution is, for the chosen chapter, to use:

```
\chapter{\vspace{-5cm}Chapter 2}
```

Adjust `vspace{}` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. you've save me lots of time.