# Move chapter title to the top left of page

Tags: formatting, chapters

I am trying to create a document in latex but I am having difficulties with the chapter location.

On each page of my document I want one chapter, but I want to have it in the top left of the page. However, in my attempt there seems to be a big white gap.

Below is a screenshot of what I am seeing
[image]
[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass
[oneside,landscape,tikz,border=2pt,png]
{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}

\tikzset{sequence item/.append style={
        /utils/exec={\ifnum\xi=1
            \tikzset{signal from=nowhere}
            \fi
        }
    }
}

\usepackage[left=0.2in,right=0.2in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}


\usepackage[
automark,
autooneside=false,
markcase=noupper,
headsepline,
headwidth=\the\textwidth+12mm:-5mm,
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\rehead{\leftmark}
\lohead{\rightmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{}% no chapternumber in header
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{\thepage}}}

% define new layers
\DeclareNewLayer[
background,
oddpage,
align=tr,
hoffset=\paperwidth,
voffset=0pt,%distance from top
width=1cm,% width of the swatch
height=\dimexpr\voffset+1in+\topmargin+\headheight\relax,% height of the swatch
contents={\textcolor{swatchcolor}{\rule{\layerwidth}{\layerheight}}}
]{swatch.odd}
\DeclareNewLayer[
clone=swatch.odd,
evenpage,
align=l,
hoffset=0pt
]{swatch.even}

\DeclareNewLayer[
foreground,
oddpage,
align=br,
hoffset=\paperwidth,
voffset=\paperheight,
width=3em,
height=2\baselineskip,
contents={{%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
        \colorbox{white}{\parbox[c][\layerheight][c]{\layerwidth}{\centering\pagemark}}%
}}
]{pagenumberouterbottom.odd}
\DeclareNewLayer[
clone=pagenumberouterbottom.odd,
evenpage,
align=bl,
hoffset=0pt
]{pagenumberouterbottom.even}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\color{black}\bfseries}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{pagenumberouterbottom.odd,pagenumberouterbottom.even}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain}{pagenumberouterbottom.odd,pagenumberouterbottom.even}

% add layers to every pagestyle
\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{swatch.odd,swatch.even}

\newcommand\swatchcolor[1]{\colorlet{swatchcolor}{#1}}
\swatchcolor{white}

%Font

\usepackage{carlito}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Carlito}



\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \vspace{-2in}
    \chapter*{First chapter}\swatchcolor{red}
    
    \Blindtext[1]
    
    \newpage
    \chapter{Second chapter}\swatchcolor{blue}

    \Blindtext[1]
    
    \chapter{Third chapter}\swatchcolor{green}

    \Blindtext[1]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicates: [How to decrease spacing before chapter title?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63390/5764), [Remove white space before a single chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298113/5764)

Answer (score 2):

By messing around with the `top` option provided by the `geometry` package I've come up with this:
[image: hard fix]
which is a fix, but it is not really pleasing and it changes the page format globally (as you can see the red rectangle in the top right corner is now gone).

Another way of removing the whitespace is through the `titlesec` package.

I personally do not see any issues with the title being in the centre of the page (I also think it's an intended feature). If you're trying to achieve a presentation style it would be better to use the `beamer` class.

Why not use the standard portrait page format?

#### Code

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    top = -2cm,
    left=0.2in,
    right=0.2in,
    bottom=0.5in
}
```

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-150pt}{40pt}
```

Comment: Hi, hadn't really considered the beamer class before. However, I am using a smart diagram and it doesn't seem to work in the beamer class. Therefore I'm trying to force it the other way. Ideally my headings will be in a similar position as a frame header is on the beamer class

Comment: Hi, did the `titlesec` package help by any means?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't seem to change the position (without the top -2). But like you mentioned it deletes the marks in the top right of the page. I've added a new screenshot with the showframe option. Is there anyway to move the header to there?

Comment: the `fancyhdr` package offers this kind of options; [here](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) is the manual

Answer (score 0):

The titlesec package came to mind, it include `\titlespacing*{\chapter}{left space}{vertical space before title}{vertical space after title}` which allows you to adjust the position of chapter.

In order to do this you have to also change titleformat of chapter. From their guide (titlesec.pdf https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec):

> \titlespacing does not work with either \chapter and \part unless you change
> its title format as well by means of \titleformat, the simple settings, or \titleclass.

It has to be combined with edit in geometry of the page.

```
\setlength{\textwidth}{width page}
\setlength{\textheight}{height page}
```